# TypeError: MimeTypes.guess_type() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'

Tags: python, mime-types

I'm trying to use the function `MimeTypes.guess_type()`

```
for file in os.listdir(attachDir):
        path_file = os.path.join(attachDir, file)
        url = urllib.request.pathname2url(path_file)
        content_type, encoding = MimeTypes.guess_type(url)
```

like this but I keep getting this error

```
TypeError: MimeTypes.guess_type() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

I have tried about every way of converting my `pathfile` variable to a URL but I just keep getting this error and im out of options at this point.

Does anyone know what im doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: How did you import and/or define `MimeTypes`? You should either use `mimetypes.get_type()` or if you use `mimetypes.MimeTypes` you have to create an instance of this class before calling `get_type` on it.

Comment: @Matthias `from mimetypes import MimeTypes` this is how I imported MimeTypes, I have tried both of your suggestions but I get the same error on all variations

Comment: Did you do a simple `import mimetypes` and then call `content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(url)`? There is a big difference between `mimetypes` and `MimeTypes`.

Comment: @Matthias u were right.. the mimetypes without capital M did the job :D Thank you very much!

Comment: `mimetypes` is the module itself and [`guess_type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_type) is a function in this module. `mimetypes.MimeType` is a class in this module and you have to create an instance of this class to call the method [`guess_type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.MimeTypes.guess_type) on it.